# (#100) Unknown fields: username facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We had built widgets for Facebook in Salesforce (Force.Com) Enterprise Version Environment using their API which has stopped working from some time. 
We are getting error of "Unknown field:Username" when we are using username in the endpoint url on the profile search. Although, we know that username is no longer available in the endpoint URL from V2.0. So , anyone kindly suggest any other way to make profile search possible(on username) without  using username in the endpoint URL.

Error : (#100) Unknown fields: username

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

To search for a username is no longer possible. You can try

```
/search?q=mark%20zuckerberg&type=user
```

to search for a user by his real name.